How to get return to start destination in Nav Graph
I have a bottom navigation set up and the "users" screen is the first screen that is started when a user is logged in. I am trying to use previousBackStackEntry and I saw in the documentation that it skips all entries associated with the NavGraph. How does that make sense? Since it's skipping it, if I click the like screen which isn't a part of the BottomNavigation, then click the "users" screen again, it will show the like screen because it doesn't go back to the "users" screen in the stack because it's skipping it so it's showing the wrong screen when you click the "users" icon.
I've tried including save state, popUpToBuilder, inclusive, launchSingleTop, and restoreState and I've also tried without them and none of it has worked.
Again, I just want to return to the "users" screen and it show that screen like it does the other screens.
Here's my NavGraph
````NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    //set to user for now but usually will be this when function
    startDestination =
    when (startDestination) {
        0 -> "login"
        1 -> "users"
        else -> "login"
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) {
    composable<Login> {
        val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        LoginScreen(
            { navController.navigate(Users.route) },
            { navController.navigate(Signup.route) },
            loginViewModel,
            userViewModel,
            firebaseViewModel,
            authViewModel,
            dataStore,
            DispatchersModule.providesIoDispatcher(),
            DispatchersModule.providesMainDispatcher(),
            ScopeModule.providesTestScope()
        )
    }
    composable("signup") {
        val signupViewModel: SignupViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        SignupScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            signupViewModel,
            authViewModel,
            dataStore
        )
    }
    composable("search") {
        val searchViewModel: SearchViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        SearchScreen(
            navController,
            editProfileViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            dataStore,
            searchViewModel,
            userViewModel
        )
    }
    composable("profile") {
        val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        ProfileScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            authViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            profileViewModel,
            firebaseViewModel,
            dataStore
        )
    }
    composable("users") {
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            val scope =
                CoroutineScope(DispatchersModule.providesIoDispatcher())
            scope.launch {
                NetworkBoundResource().createUser(userViewModel)

                client =
                    GetStreamClientModule.provideGetStreamClient(
                        context,
                        userViewModel
                    )
            }
        }

        UsersScreen(
            navController,
            editProfileViewModel,
            userViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            dataStore
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "userProfile/{userId}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
        val arguments =
            requireNotNull(navBackStackEntry.arguments)
        val userId = arguments.getString("userId")

        val bookmarkViewModel: BookmarkViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val sentLikeViewModel: SentLikeViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val receivedLikeViewModel: ReceivedLikeViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val likeViewModel: LikeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()

//            val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val userWhoBlockedYouViewModel: UserWhoBlockedYouViewModel =
hiltViewModel()
val blockViewModel: BlockViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        // Pass the userId and ViewModel to the ProfileScreen
        UserProfileScreen(
            navController,
            userId ?: "",
            userViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            sentLikeViewModel,
            receivedLikeViewModel,
            likeViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            blockedUserViewModel,
            userWhoBlockedYouViewModel,
            blockViewModel,
            dataStore,
            DispatchersModule.providesIoDispatcher()
        )
    }
    composable("shots") {

        val sentShotViewModel: SentShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val ifSeenReceivedShotViewModel: IfSeenReceivedShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val receivedShotViewModel: ReceivedShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val shotViewModel: ShotViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()

        ShotsScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            sentShotViewModel,
            ifSeenReceivedShotViewModel,
            receivedShotViewModel,
            shotViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            dataStore,
            DispatchersModule.providesIoDispatcher()
        )
    }
    composable("editProfile") {
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        EditProfileScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel
        )
    }
    composable("editProfile/{suggestion}") { backStackEntry ->
        val suggestion =
            backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("suggestion")
        val editProfileViewModel: EditProfileViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        EditProfileScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel
        )
    }
    composable("genderSearch") {
        GenderSearchScreen(navController)
    }
    composable("preview") {
        val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        PreviewScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            DispatchersModule.providesIoDispatcher()
        )
    }
    composable("bookmark") {
        val bookmarkViewModel: BookmarkViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        BookmarkScreen(
            navController,
            userViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            dataStore
        )
    }
    composable("like") {
        val receivedLikeViewModel: ReceivedLikeViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val sentLikeViewModel: SentLikeViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val likeViewModel: LikeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        LikeScreen(
            navController = navController,
            userViewModel,
            receivedLikeViewModel,
            sentLikeViewModel,
            likeViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            dataStore,
            DispatchersModule.providesIoDispatcher()
        )
    }
    composable(
        "camera/{userId}",
        listOf(navArgument("userId") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
        val arguments =
            requireNotNull(navBackStackEntry.arguments)
        val userId = arguments.getString("userId")
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        CameraScreen(
            navController = navController,
            userId,
            userViewModel.getYourUserId()
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "userProfile/{userId}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
        val arguments =
            requireNotNull(navBackStackEntry.arguments)
        val userId = arguments.getString("userId")

        val bookmarkViewModel: BookmarkViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val sentLikeViewModel: SentLikeViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val receivedLikeViewModel: ReceivedLikeViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val likeViewModel: LikeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()

//            val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val userWhoBlockedYouViewModel: UserWhoBlockedYouViewModel =
hiltViewModel()
val blockViewModel: BlockViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        // Pass the userId and ViewModel to the ProfileScreen
        UserProfileScreen(
            navController,
            userId ?: "",
            userViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            sentLikeViewModel,
            receivedLikeViewModel,
            likeViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            blockedUserViewModel,
            userWhoBlockedYouViewModel,
            blockViewModel,
            dataStore,
            dispatcher
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "playShot/{currentUserId}/{currentUserShot}/{shotType}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("currentUserId") {
                type = NavType.StringType
            },
            navArgument("currentUserShot") {
                type = NavType.StringType
            },
            navArgument("shotType") {
                type = NavType.StringType
            }
        )
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
        val arguments =
            requireNotNull(navBackStackEntry.arguments)
        val currentUserIdValue =
            arguments.getString("currentUserId")
        val currentUserShotValue =
            arguments.getString("currentUserShot")
        val shotTypeValue = arguments.getString("shotType")

        val playShotViewModel: PlayShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val receivedShotViewModel: ReceivedShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val ifSeenReceivedShotViewModel: IfSeenReceivedShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val sentShotViewModel: SentShotViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()

        if (currentUserIdValue != null && currentUserShotValue != null && shotTypeValue != null) {
            PlayShotScreen(
                navController,
                currentUserIdValue,
                currentUserShotValue,
                shotTypeValue,
                receivedShotViewModel,
                ifSeenReceivedShotViewModel,
                sentShotViewModel,
                playShotViewModel,
                userViewModel,
                firebaseViewModel
            )
        }
        // Pass the userId and ViewModel to the ProfileScreen

    }
    composable(
        route = "channels"
    ) {
        val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel =
            hiltViewModel()
        val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
        val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel<EditProfileViewModel>()
        val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel<LocationViewModel>()
        val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookmarkViewModel>()
        ChannelsScreen(
            navController = navController,
            userViewModel,
            editProfileViewModel,
            locationViewModel,
            bookmarkViewModel,
            dataStore,
            firebaseViewModel
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "channel/{channelId}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("channelId") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
        val arguments = navBackStackEntry.arguments
        val channelId = arguments?.getString("channelId")
        if (channelId != null) {
            ChannelScreen(navController, channelId)
        }
    }
    composable(
        route = "filter"
    ) {
        val filterViewModel: FilterViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        FilterScreen(
            navController = navController,
            filterViewModel = filterViewModel
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "blockedUsers"
    ) {

//            val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val userWhoBlockedYouViewModel: UserWhoBlockedYouViewModel =
hiltViewModel()
val userViewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
Log.d("NavGraph", "userViewModel - $userViewModel")
val blockedUserViewModel: BlockedUserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val editProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val locationViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val bookmarkViewModel = hiltViewModel()
BlockedUsersScreen(
navController, userViewModel, editProfileViewModel, locationViewModel,
bookmarkViewModel, blockedUserViewModel,
userWhoBlockedYouViewModel, dataStore
)
}
// Define other destinations here
}````
Here's how I have BottomNavigationItem set up
 BottomNavigationItem(
            selected = if (currentDestination?.route == topLevelRoutes[0].route) {
                usersIsSelected = true
                true
            } else {
                usersIsSelected = false
                false
            },
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = topLevelRoutes[0].icon,
                    contentDescription = topLevelRoutes[0].name,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(28.dp),
                    tint = if (usersIsSelected) Color(0xFFFF6F00) else Color.Black
                )
            },
//                        label = { Text(topLevelRoute.name) },
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(topLevelRoutes[0].route) {
                    // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                    // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        inclusive = false
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                    // reselecting the same item
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                    restoreState = true
                }
            },
            selectedContentColor = Color(0xFFFF6F00),
            unselectedContentColor = Color.Black
        )


Please edit your post and also show how you set up your NavGraph and how you navigate to the LikeScreen. Are UserScreen and LikeScreen part of a nested NavGraph?

I am using navigate("users") or navigate("like") within the screens to navigate to them. I am changing this after reading navigation documentation but I've added the navgraph set up above. Thanks for the reply.
